# Why can't I change screens on click?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a game using Kivy.  I have created just a start screen and game screen.  The app won't run and I get error "TypeError: bind() takes exactly 0 positional arguments (1 given)".  So it sounds like there is some problem when I try to bind a screen action to the "press to start" image.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

#beginning of screen manager code

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass
class Game(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name = "menu"))
sm.add_widget(Game(name = "game"))

#end of screen manager code

class IconButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class MoveableImage(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)


    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.x -= 6
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/jeezyleft.zip'
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.x += 6
            self.source ='selectionscreen/jeezyright.zip'
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.y -= 6
            self.source ='selectionscreen/jeezyright.zip'
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.y += 6
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/jeezyback.zip'
        else:
            return False
        return True

    def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/jeezyleft1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/jeezyright1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/jeezyright1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/jeezyback2.png'
        else:
            return False
        return True


class gameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #instantiate menuscreen class
        p = MenuScreen()
        clickme = IconButton(source='selectionscreen/presstostart.png')
        #clickme = Label(text='Press to Start [ref=Start]Start[/ref]', markup=True)
        clickme.bind(sm.switch_to(Game(), direction='right'))
        p.add_widget(clickme)
        return p 


        #instantiate gamescreen class
        m = Game()
        wimg = MoveableImage(source='selectionscreen/jeezyright1.png',    anim_available=True, anim_delay=.15)
        m.add_widget(wimg)






if __name__ == '__main__':
    gameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this on irc when you asked, but I guess you got disconnected:

03:51 < inclement> On line 12 you create the Game class, but do you intend this to be called GameScreen? Your code as pasted will probably crash, as 
                       you refer to GameScreen but don't declare it

03:52 < inclement> On line 70 you switch to a Game, but this is an empty screen since it has no behaviour

03:53 < inclement> If you want to switch to the one created on line 73, set its 'current' property to 'game', *don't* use switch_to

Also, your syntax for bind is wrong, you are *calling* `switch_to` when you should *pass* it. Use `functools.partial` to give it arguments at this stage (returning a new function that automatically gets those arguments).

I'm just pasting this quickly because I only have a couple of minutes, I'll write more later if it isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am having trouble wrapping my head around this part.  I will be on IRC all day trying to get help.